# How to print the test seed in Haskell's test-framework?

Tags: haskell, quickcheck, test-framework

The [`test-framework` docs](https://batterseapower.github.io/test-framework/) state that it supports "Reporting of the seed used upon a failed QuickCheck run, so you can reproduce the failure if necessary." However the default output does not display this, and I cannot find any command line option that will turn this on.

Is there a way of doing this in `test-framework`, or will I have to manually print the [`usedSeed`](http://haddock.stackage.org/lts-5.2/QuickCheck-2.8.1/Test-QuickCheck.html#v:usedSeed) from QuickCheck?

Comment: [As far as I can see](https://github.com/haskell/test-framework/blob/master/quickcheck2/Test/Framework/Providers/QuickCheck2.hs) the seed gets only reported on error, never on success.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As i also was interested in the answer of this question it came to my mind, that result, searched for, is verbosed output of the test. This brought me to the answer on hoogle:
https://www.haskell.org/hoogle/?hoogle=verboseCheck

So instead of using `quickCheck :: Testable prop => prop -> IO ()`

```
main = quickCheck propertyToTest
```

giving just an output of:

> +++ OK, passed 100 tests.

use `verboseCheck :: Testable prop => prop -> IO ()`

```
main = verboseCheck propertyToTest
```

giving verbosed, detailed output like this example for each test (Passed: for 100 times):

> Passed:
>   [-83,-52,7,-3,-92,-52,21,18,48,-72,-93,74,-30,-1,88,57,39,-20,-92,-98,-85,8,-92,22,-83,82,-39,49,70,65,-35,-7,66,38,-76,92,0,-94,-28,68,43,21,-70,25,76,39,-31,-37,-30,-1,-39,-34,14,-5,-19,54,-21,-19,-3,10,68,74,50,13,-9,54,41,-78,-77,28,-17,76,-41,-51,17,-90,56,25,58,90]
>
> ...  99 others ...
>
> +++ OK, passed 100 tests.

As there was no answer to this question and i got it by my own, i created an account here and share it

Comment: So is each element of that list the test seed?

Comment: "So is each element of that list the test seed? – Will Sewell"

...
when You write your own Generator, you can see by yourself:
..
charGen :: Gen Char
charGen = elements "abcd"
..
prop_charToNumAndBackAgain :: Property
prop_charToNumAndBackAgain = forAll charGen 
    (\c -> chr (fromEnum c)  == c)
..
main :: IO ()
main = do
    verboseCheck prop_charToNumAndBackAgain
..
*Tests> main
Passed:  
'd'

Passed:  
'c'

Passed:  
'a'

Passed:  
'd'